# Detect if elements are within pairs of interval limits

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I have arrays as:

```
A = np.array([1, 6,  4, 4, 5, 6])
B = np.array([5, 40, 4, 6, 54,7]) #same size as A but every element of B is greater than corresponding element of A
C = np.array([6, 3])
```

I want to find all rows of `A` and `B` such that `C>=A` and `C<=B`. Same rows of `A and B` form pairs so have to selected together.

So, output array will be:

```
For C[0] = 6
Aout = [6, 4, 5, 6]
Bout = [40, 6, 54, 7]

ForC[1] = 3
Aout = [1]
Bout = [5]
```

Hence, final output looks as:

```
Aout = [1, 6, 4, 5, 6]
Bout = [5, 40, 6, 54, 7]
```

Currently I am thinking of using `numpy.where` and looping through each element of `C` but considering I have very large size `A, B and C` it seems like a very inefficient process.

If there is an easier way to do this using pandas I will prefer that.

Comment: To clarify - you want to get all elements of `A` and `B` such that there is a `j` that satisfies `A[i] <= C[j] <= B[i]`? I'm not sure where you meant when you wrote "rows".

Comment: Don't you just need to find the `max` of `C` and compare against `A`  and the `min` of `C` to compare agains `B`. Why isn't `1` in your first case `1 <= 6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prospective solution**

It seems `A` and `B` are acting as the lower and upper boundaries, sort of like interval boundaries and our task is to detect if any of the elements from `C` is in each of those intervals. For such boundary related problems, often [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) could be used with its optional `side` argument that accepts `left` and `right` as input arguments. This function lets us get the first index where each element to be searched exists on the side that's fed to the `side` argument. So, we need to look for the indices where those `left` and `right` sided matching indices for each of the pair of `A` and `B` elements occur respectively. The cases where those are same would indicate that the element is on the same side of the boundary limits i.e. not within the boundary limits for that pair. Thus, we need to look for inequality as the final measure.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
def ingrps_searchsorted(A, B, C):    
    # searchsorted needs the first input to be sorted
    S = np.sort(C)

    # Use searchsorted and look for     
    return np.searchsorted(S, A, 'left') != np.searchsorted(S, B, 'right')
```

This will give us a mask, say `m`, which we need to mask onto `A` and `B` for the final outputs : `A[m]` and `B[m]`.

**Runtime test**

Other approaches -

```
# MSeifert's soln1
def ingrps_loop(A, B, C):
    mask = np.zeros(A.shape, dtype=bool)
    for item in C:
        mask |= (A<=item) & (B>=item)
    return mask

# MSeifert's soln2
def ingrps_broadcasting(A, B, C):  
    return ((A[:, None]<=C) & (B[:, None]>=C)).max(axis=1)
```

Timings and verification for mask creation :

```
In [342]: # Setup inputs so that around 20% matches exist
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,50,(10000))
     ...: B = A + np.random.randint(0,50,(10000))
     ...: C = np.random.randint(0,100,(10000))
     ...: 

In [343]: np.allclose(ingrps_loop(A, B, C), ingrps_broadcasting(A, B, C))
Out[343]: True

In [344]: np.allclose(ingrps_loop(A, B, C), ingrps_searchsorted(A, B, C))
Out[344]: True

In [345]: %timeit ingrps_loop(A, B, C)
     ...: %timeit ingrps_broadcasting(A, B, C)
     ...: %timeit ingrps_searchsorted(A, B, C)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 ms per loop

In [346]: # Setup inputs so that around 20% matches exist
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,50,(100000))
     ...: B = A + np.random.randint(0,50,(100000))
     ...: C = np.random.randint(0,100,(100000))
     ...: 

In [347]: %timeit ingrps_loop(A, B, C)
     ...: %timeit ingrps_searchsorted(A, B, C)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 8.18 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 26.5 ms per loop

In [348]: 8180/26.5 # Speedup number with proposed solution over loopy one
Out[348]: 308.6792452830189
```

Comment: This will further improve the time for your solution as my C is already sorted.

Answer (score 5):

Especially if you have very large `A` and `B` the overhead of looping through `C` will be almost neglectable. However if `C` is very long but `A` and `B` are short then you need to think about a broadcasting approach because then a python loop will introduce a significant overhead.

## The simple approach with explicit loop

```
mask = np.zeros(A.shape, dtype=bool)
for item in C:
    mask |= (A<=item) & (B>=item)

A[mask], B[mask]  # select the valid elements
```

## The broadcasting approach

```
mask= ((A[:, None]<=C) & (B[:, None]>=C)).max(axis=1)

A[mask], B[mask]  # select the valid elements
```

The broadcasting approach will however create big (`size= A.size * C.size`) intermediate arrays, so if `A`, `B` **and** `C` are huge this will require a lot of memory.